Lego mindstorm proposal going nowhere

Possible Duplicate:
Is Lego Mindstorms on-topic? 

With "Is lego mindstorm on topic" in mind, I see, in area51, a lego mindstorm proposal that is stuck in its raising commitment phase. I would recommend for both the health of our stack site and for their interest to tell them to join in once we get on the public beta phase. 
(hint : there is even such a suggestion there "There are a proposal for general Lego. It might be better to use this with tag mindstorm instead of having a separate site for Mindstorms. – awe Aug 4 '10 at 9:00")

I intended to do that too, but seing Dori's answer, it's all taken care of already.

The issue that I see is that in general (as shown by this question) mindstorms related questions will almost certainly have an element of both build and program (otherwise they could just be tagged technic).
So a question that arises is "do we accept Mindstorms related programming questions?" because until the "Theoretical and Applied Robotics1" makes it out of proposal/commitment the only real place they have to ask is the Mindstorms tag on StackOverflow.
1 That being the only likely option now, as the robotics proposal has recently been deleted due to not enough activity.

I don't see anything wrong with using the Mindstorms tag on StackOverflow for pure programming questions, but I guess some will be asked here anyway. Wait and see, I guess.

I don't either, but I certainly found that my Mindstorms experiments usually went along the lines of "I want to create a robot that does [this], how do I build it, and how do I program it" - the available sensors and bricks limited both parts.

there are programmers lurking on this stack, but I think any programming question should go on stack overflow.

@joe, makes sense to me.
